# React: how to use axios/fetch to get data from API that runs on localhost?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot rest API that I run on my `http://localhost:8080`. I am building a frontend in React, and I would like to use the API, but something is not working.

I have this code:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });

  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/player')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

The first `axios()` works, the second not. I don't see a reason what the difference is... My spring-boot app does not even get the GET request, or else it would log it.

Comment: Can you test the URL in the browser? It works?

Comment: What error do you see in the browser console or network tab? My guess is either A) The former uses CORS to allow all origins and the latter doesn't and you're doing the call cross-origin (see: [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), or B) There's an error you haven't mentioned.

Comment: (And I can confirm that the former seems to allow all origins via CORS.)

Comment: as @T.J.Crowder mentioned above it should be for CORS policy or if you get 404 error it means maybe you point to wrong place in your localhost

Answer (score 0):

Use this cors set up for your @Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*", origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping(value = "/api/player")
public ResponseEntity<?> myMethod(...) {
    //do things
    ...
}
```

and add cors to your header request:

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/player',{
        headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

or disable cors in your spring security config:

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().headers().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/player").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```